# Firebase cloud function returns UNAUTHENTICATED when logged in with email/password

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been working on a Flutter app which needs to call Firebase functions. The app is supposed to use OIDC for authentication. There's currently one function deployed - the basic Hello World https one that Google provided. The function is set to require authentication, which I tried to set up using email and password. The function is called like this:

`HttpsCallable callable = await FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west3').httpsCallable(func); final response = await callable.call();`

If I'm logged in, I get UNAUTHENTICATED exception, if I'm not I instead get PERMISSION_DENIED. Everywhere I look online people suggest setting the functions to require no authentication, or adding Cloud Functions Invoker to the allUsers role, which doesn't seem right. Are these funtions supposed to be public? Is the HTTPS authentication that Cloud Functions provides meant to be used only with Google Accounts? Are you

supposed to authenticate within the function code itself? I would appreciate any advice on this!

When logged in with email and password, I get:

`E/flutter (21310): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/unauthenticated] UNAUTHENTICATED`

Without logging in I instead get:

`E/flutter (21310): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/permission-denied] PERMISSION_DENIED`